# import torchvision.transforms as transforms Module Not Found Error: No module named 'torchvision'

Tags: torchvision

I am using python and it gives this error, anyone can help me, thanks
No module named 'torchvision'
Run and giving error

```
C:\Users\Dr Shahid\Desktop\Microscopy images\RepVGG-main>python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    import torchvision.transforms as transforms
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torchvision'
```

adding module and still giving error

```
C:\Users\Dr Shahid>pip install transforms
Collecting transforms
  Downloading transforms-0.1.tar.gz (29 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: transforms
  Building wheel for transforms (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for transforms: filename=transforms-0.1-py3-none-any.whl size=39349 sha256=6591fdbe00cb5835e8365f07392c1e583f809f88fabeb098cf0671370387f8b0
  Stored in directory: c:\users\dr shahid\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\73\8d\26\be8b7e278f01d5093d18fc99c8158bd8528403242c852a558c
Successfully built transforms
Installing collected packages: transforms
Successfully installed transforms-0.1

C:\Users\Dr Shahid>
```